# Ubuntu 23.04 - Microphone not working for Lenovo Ideapad 1

Tags: sound, microphone, 23.04

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad 1 and installed Ubuntu 23.04. Everything seems to work fine except for the microphone.

Was anyone able to solve that problem ? I am not sure if it is a driver or configuration problem.

Audio hardware details below: (lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3)

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
04:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:3812]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP [1022:1649]
--
04:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor [1022:15e2] (rev 6f)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor [17aa:3862]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp6x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
04:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller [17aa:3860]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1505]
```

Comment: Have you checked your mic is not muted?